# Корректно ли использовать статические свойства во viewModel в паттерне MVVM в случае "одна viewModel для нескольких view"?"

Tags: ios, mvvm

Есть одна вью модель с некоторым количеством свойств (имя и возраст). В первом вью контроллере отображаются значения этих свойств (например Joe 30). При нажатии на кнопку происходит переход на второй вью контроллер, в котором можно отредактировать эти два значения (на, допустим, Misha 40). Соответственно, при возвращении на первый вью контроллер, в лейблах должны отобразиться эти новые значения. Данную задачу можно решить двумя способами: это использовать статические свойства:

```
class ViewModel {
    static var name = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "Joe")
    static var age = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "30")
}
```

Либо передавать self во второй контроллер

```
class ViewModel {
    var name = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "Joe")
    var age = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "30")

    func foo() -> ViewModel {
        return self
    }
}
```

Вопрос: какой из этих подходов правильный? Или можно сделать как-то иначе, сделав ещё одну вью модель (EditViewModel, например (но в таком случае я не знаю как обновить данные в первом вью))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте необходимые поля. Не используйте статические поля.

Если подходит в вашем варианте использование одной ViewModel в двух ViewController (один на чтение, второй на запись одних и тех же данных грубо говоря) - используйте одну.

Классический подход в данном случае - delegate.

Comment: Я стараюсь использовать реактивщину, с ней очень удобно. Обновил в одном месте, а в другом все обновилось автоматом. Использование одного viewModel оправдано - спасибо за ответ! Насколько я понимаю, вы склоняетесь к использованию моего второго варианта, верно? То есть не создаем новый объект, а передаем уже существующий. Ну и во втором контроллере при изменении значений у этого переданного объекта автоматически обновятся значения во вью у первого контроллера. И все без статики.

Comment: @Tkas да, либо Ваш второй вариант, либо передача отдельных полей (может нужно менять только что-то одно, к примеру, age).